# C3 creating a bar chart with categorical JSON data

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

How do you specify the x-axis labels for a C3 bar chart with data loaded via JSON? I don't see anything in the docs and the closest I found was [this](http://c3js.org/samples/data_stringx.html) but it only gives an example for data specified in column format, whereas I have data specified in JSON format like [in this example](http://c3js.org/samples/data_json.html)

My attempt:

```
const chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                // x: "title",
                json: bookData,
                type: "bar",
                keys: {
                    value: ["count"]
                }
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    tick: {
                        values: labels,
                        rotate: 90,
                    },
                    type: "category",
                }
            },
            bindto: "#book-title-histogram",
        });
```

By uncommenting `x: "title"` it leads to the plot to no longer be visible. With that line commented out, the axis is simply blank.

EDIT: `bookData` is an array with each element having keys `count` and `title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like mapping your data works.

```
const bookData = [{
  count: 3,
  title: 'The Foutainhead'
},{
  count: 4,
  title: 'Fight Club'
},{
  count: 2,
  title: 'Ender\'s Game'
}]

const titles = bookData.map((obj) => {
  return obj.title
})

const counts = bookData.map((obj) => {
  return obj.count
})

console.log(titles)

const chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                x: 'title',
                y: 'count',
                json: {
                    title: titles,
                    data: counts,
                },
                type: "bar",
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    tick: {
                        count: bookData.length,
                        rotate: 45,
                    },
                    type: "category",
                }
            },
            bindto: "#book-title-histogram",
        });
```

[image]